# Do I need to notify the Prefecture upon change of job to work for an international organisation?

Tags: blue-card, employment

I live in France bordering Switzerland (Geneva) and have a EU Blue Card (valid till Aug 2025). I was employed in France till 21st Jan 2022. However, I have taken up a job in the UN effective 24th Jan 2022 in Geneva, Switzerland.  UN will get me a *carte de légitimation* (CDL) which is like a residence-cum-work permit for Switzerland.

I plan to keep my residence in France (allowed with CDL). Being UN employee, I will no longer be paying any income tax, social security, health insurance, etc. in France.

What is the process to notify the French authorities (my residence is in Haute-Savoie). What happens to my Carte Vitale?

Comment: [This document](https://www.eda.admin.ch/dam/mission-onu-omc-aele-geneve/fr/documents/Lignes-directrices-autres-OI_FR.pdf) suggests the right place to ask is the French consulate general in Geneva. It's not obvious to me that you may in fact reside in France.

Comment: I edited the question as you are not a typical cross-border worker. For the most part you do not fall under these regulations and, in fact, what you plan to do (work in Geneva and live in France) is not possible for third-country (non-EU) citizens who do not have another basis to reside in France.

Comment: @Relaxed "what you plan to do (work in Geneva and live in France) is not possible for third-country (non-EU) citizens who do not have another basis to reside in France": citation?  I know a few people who've lived in France while working for the UN, but indeed I can't think of any who were third-country nationals.

Comment: @phoog I was speaking about non-UN employees in this case. What I meant is that if it's possible, it has to be by virtue of the OP's status as a UN employee and some special agreement the consulate would know about. In other words, general rules on cross-border workers (which is what the question was ostensibly about before my edit) are not relevant and do not help here.

Comment: EU citizens can do that as well with a regular private sector job in Geneva, incidentally, that's pretty common too. But people who depend on work in Switzerland for their claim to residence cannot easily translate that to a French residence permit.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding income tax,** people who work in Geneva don't pay it in France anyway, UN or not. You should file a tax return and you will find a special box for your UN salary (*revenus provenant d'une organisation internationale*). If you don't have any other income, filing won't make much of a difference in practice as you cannot get a fine if you did not owe any taxes to begin with. However, the document you get in return (*avis d'imposition*) is useful for many purposes. Somewhat surprisingly, if it shows 0 taxes, it might make you eligible for reduced rate at school cantines and many other social services, no matter what your income actually is.

Note that unless you are yourself a diplomat, you are not generally exempt from all taxes, only the taxes covered by the agreement between the organisation employing you and France would be. Usually, that would cover your salary, sometimes privileges on buying/importing a car every X years, etc. Other income you might derive from, say, investments or a property in France you are renting out could be taxable.

**Regarding health insurance,** as an employee of an international organisation, you are indeed outside the scope of the French health insurance system, you do not pay into it but you don't get a *carte vitale* or coverage either. I am more familiar with the status of EU employees but either way, you should ask the relevant UN agency for advice on healthcare coverage.

Under this status, getting healthcare in France can be a bit of a challenge as healthcare providers are not familiar with it. Since health insurance is virtually universal, they are not used to handle someone without a national health insurance number. Mostly, you have to pay all the costs out of pocket and then ask your insurer to pay you back. You might find healthcare providers who are more familiar with that situation in Geneva itself.

An additional complication comes from the fact that you already have a *carte vitale* and health care coverage based on your earlier job. If you were unemployed and would still reside in France, you would be entitled to health insurance indefinitely. This is not designed to cover diplomats or UN employees (most of them wouldn't have prior rights under the French health insurance system) but that might be a loophole you could benefit from. Supplementary insurance (*mutuelle*) works differently. I would still advise getting coverage through the UN in any case.

Comment: "unless you are a diplomat": officers and employees of international organizations are treated like diplomats, though an employee of the UN in Geneva wouldn't be able to claim the attendant privileges or immunities in France unless there were some specific agreement providing for this.  The same would be true of a true diplomat, such as a third-country representative to the UN in Geneva when present in France.  I seem to recall, though, that Switzerland issues _cartes de légitimation_ to people who live in France, and I'm not certain that they all have an independent basis for that residence.

Comment: @phoog Not all of them no. I don't know exactly what specific agreement UN agencies have with France but there is a clear distinction between, e.g. an employee of the EU or the European patent office (who do not pay national income taxes on the salary coming from the international organisation but are otherwise treated like private citizens) and a head of office, judge, EU commissioner, etc. with diplomatic immunity, diplomatic passport and CD plates on their car.

Comment: Re: *carte de légitimation* and residence in France, that's what the document I mentioned in a comment suggests as well, without elaborating on what the rules or criteria might be.

Comment: Well I don't know the specifics in France, but in Switzerland there are several levels, each of which enjoys slightly more privileges and immunities than the next.  But even the Vienna Convention excludes real estate matters from the scope of immunity, so I think all diplomats have to pay tax on income from renting out a property.  I suppose the most important question here is really the conditions for maintaining the French blue card, in particular whether a job in Geneva would allow one to retain it, whether as a normal cross-border commuter or as an employee of the UN.

Comment: @phoog Good point, I thought real estate would have been covered for employees with diplomatic status but it seems I was wrong about that. Re: Blue card, it's the usual with French residence permits, it doesn't lapse immediately, can be revoked (but I wouldn't expect the *préfecture* to bother necessarily) and definitely won't be renewable. That's the potential loophole I alluded to at the end but I thought it was more useful for the OP to understand the consequences of their new status and to double-check whether they can in fact reside in France on that basis.